# Problem compiling dll files with CUDA FFT package (Windows 64)

Tags: python, dll, cuda, cufft

I'm trying to compile some dll files with some c++ and CUDA functions to quickly process some data that I receive in a python program (160MB/s from an acquisition card to be FFT). The DLL works fine with CUDA functions, but stops working whenever I add a function from the CUFFT library.

At the moment i have a .cu file with some simple CUDA functions as the example below shows.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuFFT.h>

extern "C" void  __declspec(dllexport)  GPU_copyto(float *array, float *data_p, int offset, int ndata) // offset and ndata are in bytes
{  
   offset/=2;
   ndata/=2;
   cudaMemcpy(data_p+offset, array+offset, ndata*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
```

I can compile the example into a .dll with the following command:

```
nvcc -lcufft -o cuda_avg.dll -shared cuda_average.cu
```

and then import it in python with:

```
cuda_avg_dll=ctypes.CDLL('./cuda_avg.dll', mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
```

With this simple flow I was able to use some simple CUDA functions in Python to allocate memory on the GPU, transfer data, do arithmetic and copy the data back.

**The problem starts when I want to use the CUFFT library to compute a FFT of the data.**
Adding a function from the CUFFT package, like cufftPlan1d(), outputs an error neither from the compiler or linker. I get the following error when loading the DLL into Python.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manip.batm\Desktop\shotnoise\20240123_SI_card_test\SI_cudaFFT\SI_cuda_TEST.py", line 21, in <module>
    cuda_avg_dll=ctypes.CDLL('./cuda_avg.dll', mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "C:\Users\manip.batm\.conda\envs\qcodes\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\manip.batm\Desktop\shotnoise\20240123_SI_card_test\SI_cudaFFT\cuda_avg.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

I can use the following compiler command to generate a .exe file instead of a DLL.

```
nvcc -lcufft -o cuda_avg cuda_average.cu
```

It executes just fine and I can easily perform FFT on the GPU.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Is there any alternative to a DLL to quickly execute low level functions from a python program on windows?

I've seen on the CUDA documentation that there are both dynamically linked and statically linked libraries. Knowing that i have no idea what the difference is, can I generate a static library and load that into python? how can one do that?

Comment: You cannot link cufft statically on windows, so your link specification (`-lcufft`) will inevitably create a dependency on cufft64.dll (or whatever the cufft library is called on windows).  The error message may be telling you that it can't find your cufft DLL that is part of the windows CUDA install.  Note that this doesn't apply to the cudart library because the default behavior of `nvcc` is to link cudart statically.  That is why your initial non-cufft test case works.  You'll need to make sure that your CUDA install and its libraries can be found from your python environment.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the suggestion of Robert Crovella, I have solved the problem.
Indeed Python was not able to find the cufft64_11.dll that was needed to run de CuFFT library's functions. Adding

```
os.add_dll_directory(r"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.3\bin")
```

before loading the dll solved the problem.